# Expression in FOR command (for (int i=0; i < ([arr count]-1);i++){})

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem that I can not understand

```
NSArray *emptyArr = @[];
for (int i=0; i < ([emptyArr count]-1) ; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Did run for1");
}
```

`[emptyArr count]` - 1 is -1 but my app still runs `NSLog` command!

If I use a int variable:

```
NSArray *emptyArr = @[];
int count = [emptyArr count]-1;
for (int i=0; i < count ; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Did run for1");
}
```

then my app doesn't run `NSLog` command.

Anyone help me please!

Comment: In your first version, how many lines of output do you get? Just one?

Comment: Thanks @Frank Schmitt. I think I found the reason!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the return type of `count` is an **unsigned** `int`.  When you substract 1 from 0, you do not get -1.  Instead you underflow to the highest possible `unsigned int`.  The reason it works in the second version is because you cast it (implicitly) to an `int` in which the value -1 is legal.

Comment: Thanks! I've recognized too! :((

Comment: @borrrden +1 for Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`[emptyArr count]-1` is never less than 0 since it is unsigned. I'm guessing if you do `((int)[emptyArr count]-1)`, you will get the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by [emptyArr count] is unsigned integer.
In the first case,
[emptyArr count]-1 is 0-1 represented in 2's compliment, which is a huge number.
So it prints the log many times.

In the second case,
[emptyArr count]-1 -> You are casting the result of this to int.
0-1 -> -1 signed int.
Hence does not print.